# Get the TAG on file in S3 bucket by java - key does not exist

Tags: java, amazon-s3, tags

I tagged manually file `temp1.zip`  under bucket with TAG:
`key = VirusScan value = succeed`. I want to verify the tag i have on the file from my code that indeed it is `key = VirusScan value = succeed`.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = null;
s3 = (AmazonS3)((AmazonS3ClientBuilder)((AmazonS3ClientBuilder)AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard()
   .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()))
   .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1))
   .build();
GetObjectTaggingRequest getTaggingRequest = new GetObjectTaggingRequest(bucketName, keyName);
s3.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest);
```

I am getting exception on:

```
s3.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest);
```

The specified key does not exist.

Comment: Could you please add an exeption you are getting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here `(AmazonS3)((AmazonS3ClientBuilder)((AmazonS3ClientBuilder)`?

Comment: I am trying to connect to S3. The exception is: Method threw 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception' exception. Status code = 404

Comment: I changed the keyName to be = temp1.zip and now i am getting to s3.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest) null - how can i get the value and the key?

Answer (score 0):

This code works nicely:

```
package aws.example.s3;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class GetObjectTags {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Please specify a bucket name and key name");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // snippet-start:[s3.java2.list_objects.main]
        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];

        System.out.println("Retrieving Object Tags for  " + keyName);

        final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION).build();

        try {

            GetObjectTaggingRequest getTaggingRequest = new GetObjectTaggingRequest(bucketName, keyName);

            GetObjectTaggingResult tags = s3.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest);

            List<Tag> tagSet= tags.getTagSet();

            //Iterate through the list
            Iterator<Tag> tagIterator = tagSet.iterator();

            while(tagIterator.hasNext()) {

                Tag tag = (Tag)tagIterator.next();

                System.out.println(tag.getKey());
                System.out.println(tag.getValue());
            }

        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```